C# Web API Using a Unioned SQL View - How can I update the underlying table?
I'm trying to create a C# Web API which uses EF. It connects to a SQL Database.
Currently, I have the following in my API:

UserController
IUserRepository
SQLUserRepository

In addition, I have a Domain Model called vwUsers which is a union of multiple user tables in SQL. I appreciate this is not efficient but, this is the DB design I've inherited.
The vwUsers has an extra column - Org which identifies the Org specific User table.
For example, the underlying tables are actually UserAA and UserBB  - the AA and BB being the Org element.
I then have a DTO which is essentially a replica of the vwUsers columns which is mapped using AutoMapper.
The Problem
I'm trying to write the UPDATE route but I'm not sure how to update the underlying table as I can't update a view. The following code below is what I've tried so far:
// UserController
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("{id:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromRoute] int id, [FromQuery] string org, UserUpdateRequestDto userUpdateRequestDto)
        {
            var userDomainModel = mapper.Map<vwUsers>(userUpdateRequestDto);
            userDomainModel = await userRepository.UpdateAsync(id, org, userDomainModel ); 
            if (userDomainModel == null) { return NotFound(); };

            return Ok(mapper.Map<UserDto>(userDomainModel));
        }


// IUserRepository
    public interface IUserRepository
    {
        Task<List<vwUsers>> GetAllAsync(string org, string? filterOn = null, string? filterQuery = null,
            string? sortBy = null, bool isAscending = true,
            int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 25
            );
        Task<vwUsers?> GetByIdAsync(string org, int id);

        Task<vwUsers?> UpdateAsync(int id, string org, vwUsers user);
    }

// SQLUserRepository
        // UPDATE User
        public async Task<vwUsers?> UpdateAsync(int id, string org, vwUsers user)
        {
            // Construct the SQL query with a parameter for the table name
            string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM User{org}";

            // Execute the SQL query and map the results to DbSet
            var dbSet = dbContext.Set<vwUsers>().FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery);

            var existingUser = await dbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserID == id);
            if (existingUser == null) { return null; }

            //List all fields
            var properties = typeof(vwUsers).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name != "UserID" && p.Name != "Org" && p.CanRead);
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var newValue = property.GetValue(user);
                if (newValue != null)
                {
                    var correspondingProperty = existingUser.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
                    if (correspondingProperty != null && correspondingProperty.CanWrite)
                    {
                        correspondingProperty.SetValue(existingUser, newValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            existingUser.LastUpd = DateTime.Now;

            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return existingUser ;
        }



I've never used unioned views on my UI but it seems to me like your form should be able to simply update the data relevant data point used in the union. Is there any reason why you can't simply update the relevant table?

The Unioned view is on the SQL database - it combines 3 tables together for example. But because it is a unioned view it is not updateable. I'm just not sure how to update the specific tables in the view - confusing terminology as I know view can also mean UI but I meant view within SQL

Well your approach looks solid; you're updating the underlying table based on the Org parameter provided so I guess I don't see the issue. Is there a specific problem you're having?

The issue seems to be in the SQLUserRepository. My vwUsers has an extra column for the Org but when I reference the underlying table UserAA it doesn't have Org and it's complaining that it doesn't have this column in the table. I'm quite new to C# so I'm not sure how to go about this. Do I need another DTO for the underlying User tables without the org column?
